# Cannot get Url from filebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to retrieve data url from firebase storage. I have a static function to get url, but the return is always undefined? How can I get the url of the file and store to my database?

```
uploadImageByDataURL(image, imageName, directory) {
      const uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref(`images/${directory}/${imageName}`).putString(image, 'data_url');
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', () => {
        firebase.storage().ref(`images/${directory}`).child(`${imageName}`).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          return url
        })
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the download URL happens asynchronously. Any code that requires the download URL, should be in the corresponding `then()` block. So:

```
const uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref(`images/${directory}/${imageName}`).putString(image, 'data_url');
uploadTask.on('state_changed', () => {
  firebase.storage().ref(`images/${directory}`).child(`${imageName}`).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
    firebase.database().reference().set(url);
  })
})
```